# How can I send files / pictures to Report Portal with .net client?

Tags: reportportal

I'd like to send a binary attachment to [Report Portal](http://github.com/reportportal/reportportal) with [.net client](https://github.com/reportportal/client-net). How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example is in Tests project.

https://github.com/reportportal/client-net/blob/master/ReportPortal.Client.Tests/LogItem/LogItem.cs

Find `CreateLogWithAttach` test and see code.

```
var data = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
            var log = Service.AddLogItem(new AddLogItemRequest
            {
                TestItemId = _testId,
                Text = "Log1",
                Time = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Level = LogLevel.Info,
                Attach = new Attach("file1", "application/octet-stream", data)
            });
```

Related documentation: [Log Data in ReportPortal](http://reportportal.io/docs/Log-Data-in)